# Visualforce email template in different languages

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I developed a Visualforce emailtemplate and used all the custom labels to translate into different languages.
the subject is coming as ??????? for all the languages except for english, but in preview i can able to see the subject in translated language .we are using the outlook as the mail-box.

Comment: Is your email encoding set as UTF-8? Depending on this user setting, some characters may appear incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005102&language=en_US
Check encoding, Go to your template -> Edit -> Encoding -> select Unicode (UTF-8)
It has to work.